# Line style in q-q plot in R

Tags: r, plot

Why I did get lines instead of standard bubbles in my q-q plot?
[image]

My code:

```
data <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\anton\\SanFrancisco.csv")
x <- data$ï..San.Francisco
head(x)

library("fitdistrplus")

fitnor <- fitdist(x, "norm")
fitlogis <- fitdist(x, "logis")

qqcomp(list(fitnor, fitlogis), legendtext=c("Normal", "Logistic"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for `qqcomp` - get to it by `?qqcomp`.

> `qqcomp` provides a plot of the quantiles of each theoretical
> distribution (x-axis) against the empirical quantiles of the data
> (y-axis), by default defining probability points as (1:n - 0.5)/n for
> theoretical quantile calculation (data are assumed continuous). For
> large dataset (n > 1e4), lines are drawn instead of points and
> customized with the fitpch parameter.

This is a design feature. Your data must have more than 10000 values. If that is the case, the bubbles on the q-q plot would be difficulty to individually distinguish. Additionally, they are large enough that the bubbles for one model would cover those for the other.